# ActiveRecord query to find all users who have not made a purchase in the last 3 months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have a user model that has an associated cart. Each cart has a purchased_at datetime column.
I want to select all users that have have not purchased a cart in the last 3 months.

I though a simple:

```
User.joins(:carts).where('not carts.purchased_at < ?', 3.months.ago)
```

would do the trick but this doesn't seem to be the case. I'm being returned user records who have purchased something in the past 3 months.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this is in plain active record:

```
User.joins(:carts)
  .group("users.id")
  .having("MAX(carts.purchased_at) < ?", 3.months.ago)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. Can you explain the reason for  User.column_names.map in the group method? If I replace that with group('users.id') it works just as well.

Comment: You're right about that. I ran into some strange issue when testing this in the console. But this does work. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do a raw SQL.

```
User.find_by_sql('
  SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE id NOT IN 
  (SELECT users.id FROM users LEFT JOIN carts ON users.id = carts.user_id
  WHERE carts.purchased_at < ?)
', 3.months.ago)
```

Remember that this is just a suggestion. (And i think the code needs some refactor, but you got the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem for such complex queries:

```
User.where{id.not_in User.joins{carts}.where{carts.purchased_at > 3.months.ago}}
```

Comment: Seems like a nice dsl around active record but it might be overkill to install this gem to satisfy this single case.

Comment: @KJF You can take a look at other your queries, perhaps you'll find more places to use squeel in order to avoid SQL text pieces. And by the way, don't you think you have to have `>` sign instead of `<`?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using AR3 (and ARel):

```
User.joins(:carts).where(Cart.arel_table[:purchased_at].gt(3.months.ago))
```

Comment: This just retrieves all users who have made a purchase more than 3 months ago, regardless of whether they've made a purchase in the last 3 months. I only want to see users who haven't made a purchase in the past 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MAX` and `GROUP BY` can be slow if you have have a huge cart. I would use this approach.

```
nq = Cart.where("carts.user_id = users.id AND carts.purchased_at >= ?", 3.months.ago)
User.where("NOT EXISTS (#{nq.to_sql})")
```

Better yet, I would add a column called `last_purchase_at` to the `User` model to make this query efficient.

```
class User
  # add a new column called last_purchase_at
  # index the last_purchase_at column

  def self.dormant_users(period=3.months)
    User.where("last_purchase_at <= ?", period.ago)
  end
end
```

Add after_create callback to the `Cart` model to update the `User` model.

```
class Cart
  after_create :update_user_last_purchase_at

  def update_user_last_purchase_at
    user.update_attribute(:last_purchase_at, purchased_at)
  end
end
```

Add this code to your migration script to set the `last_purchase_at` column for existing `User` models.

```
User.connection.execute("
  UPDATE users 
  JOIN (
    SELECT a.user_id, MAX(a.purchased_at) purchased_at 
    FROM carts a 
    GROUP BY a.user_id
  ) carts ON carts.user_id= users.id
  SET users.last_purchase_at = cards.purchased_at")
```

Now you can get the dormant users as follows:

```
User.dormant_users # dormant for last 6 months
User.dormant_users(6.months) # dormant for last 6 months
```